# I need to manually resolve all relative url's in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, url

Ok so this unfortunate task is due to a bug in chrome which I determined in another question: [Loading resources from html5 filesystem api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049748/loading-resources-from-html5-filesystem-api)

What I need to do is go through all the resources that may come from downloading a website, and turn any relative urls into absolute urls, in Javascript. What I could use help with is coming up with all of the cases I am going to have to handle. Here's what I can come up with:

- in html / xhtml / xml => anything with an href or src attribute
- in css => anything that matches a /url(.*)/ regex\
- javascript => probably not possible...

Is there anything else I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using jQuery or similar I'd just bite the bullet and attack the entire page source.

```
var entireHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
document.documentElement.innerHTML = entireHTML.replace('href="','href="<path(/)>');
```

How you determine  is up to you, could inject it into your doc.onready function or otherwise inject a global var into the document somewhere.

Comment: I ended up using jquery to do it.